# Java: multicast UDP socket example does not work

Tags: java, sockets, multicast

I'm learning how to use multicast UDP in Java language. I just studied the examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html).
However, after that I downloaded the codes and executed them, they work only if I run the multicast client and the multicast server in the same PC.
Hence, I tried to run multiple instance of the client and one instance of the server into a LAN network it did not work.
Finally, I deeply studied the code and take a look on the web and I found that it is correct.

My client is on GNU/linux ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS 64 bit while I tried to run other clients with same and different OS (also Windows).
I think that is not something related to OS configuration (on GNU/linux via ifconfig I saw multicast enabled), but it should be a problem of my local network. I configured the router in order to allow IGMP proxy and IGMP spoofing and I also disabled the firewall.

Then I used wireshark in order to capture the IGMP and UDP packages. I could see the client in my PC that send IGMP request to join the multicast group (address) and UDP data to the group while I could not receive any package.

What can I do?
My final goal is to test the code across Internet instead on my local LAN. Could an ISP block my multicast traffic?

Thank you

P.S.
I'm using [reserved multicast IP](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-9)
netstat -gn show that my network interface has joined the multicast group

Comment: In general, multicast will only work within a specific network and is not routed to the Internet, unless the participant networks are configured to allow it.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez thank you for your reply. Multicast should work at least on my LAN with two PC and one router.

Comment: It  should. I was just trying to save you some time if you are thinking about an Internet application...